# How to make android app fullscreen with ionic-react?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, capacitor

I created an app for android with ionic-react. Ionic react use capacitor instead of cordova. I don't understand how to use cordova plugins with my ionic-react app. There are cordova and ionic native plugin android-full-screen, but I don't understand how to use it in my app.

I will show you my App.tsx. I want my app to be full screen from start, for example on componentDidMount. Help please, I'm looking for a couple of days, but can't find how to solve this. Thanks.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Redirect, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
import {
    IonApp,
    IonRouterOutlet,
} from '@ionic/react';
import {IonReactRouter} from '@ionic/react-router';
import ScenariosPage from './pages/ScenariosPage/ScenariosPage';
import ScenarioDetail from './pages/ScenarioDetail/ScenarioDetail';

import './css/common.css'
import '@ionic/react/css/core.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/normalize.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/structure.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/typography.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/padding.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/float-elements.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-alignment.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/text-transformation.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/flex-utils.css';
import '@ionic/react/css/display.css';
import './theme/variables.css';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props: any) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { StatusBar } = Plugins;
        StatusBar.hide();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <IonApp>
                <IonReactRouter>
                    <IonRouterOutlet>

                        <Route path="/scenarios" component={ScenariosPage} exact={true}/>
                        <Route path="/scenarios/:id" component={ScenarioDetail}/>
                        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <Redirect to="/scenarios"/>}/>
                    </IonRouterOutlet>
                </IonReactRouter>
            </IonApp>
        )
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the app fullscreen from the start, and don't need to toggle it in the JS at all, then just do this on the android side without any need for a cordova plugin. Try putting this in the `onCreate` method in the `MainActivity.java` file. This is taken from the android docs on fullscreen https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

```
// Enables regular immersive mode.
// For "lean back" mode, remove SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE.
// Or for "sticky immersive," replace it with SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
  View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
  // Set the content to appear under the system bars so that the
  // content doesn't resize when the system bars hide and show.
  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
  // Hide the nav bar and status bar
  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
  | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

So first of all! You don't need to manipulate the MainActivity.java if you do your ionic application will die...

But there is an awesome little [Cordova plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-full-screen) that allows you to do the same as you would in JAVA

After you have installed the plugin you will need 2 extra packages (ionic-native/core with along rxjs) (if you don't install these your application will simply not start)

```
npm install @ionic-native/core
npm install rxjs
```

After they installed successfully
you can simply add these lines to your App.tsx or any other page or component you would like to make immersive fullscreen etc...

import {AndroidFullScreen, AndroidSystemUiFlags} from "@ionic-native/android-full-screen";

```
const AFS = async () => 
{
//Check if is immersive supported for instance
await AndroidFullScreen.isImmersiveModeSupported().then((r: any) => {
        console.log(r);
    });
//Set display with AndroidSystemUiFlags
//in my case to full screen but there is a ton of options
//As the android documentation shows if u want a fullscreen app you should use three
//flags Immersive, Fullscreen, HideNavigation
await AndroidFullScreen.setSystemUiVisibility(AndroidSystemUiFlags.Fullscreen)
//example how to set a flag
}
```

AndroidSystemUiFlag options :
[image: Cordova plugin options]

You can also set a bunch of other options base on your needs :
[image: Cordova plugin static methods]

After you have set up what you needed you can simply just start your app into an emulator or physical device with:

```
ionic capacitor run
```

Result with `fullscreen` flag :

[image: Result]

tested on Pixel 2, 3, 3a, 4 it works just fine, and also on a Samsung galaxy A51

Comment: This version of doing might be a little out of data... But I've found also a nicer and in my opinion an easier way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a few options to do this. First, what I posted a few hours ago after then I have noticed that, if you are not using immersive sticky you should write a handler that set back the flags (based on [VIDEO OF FLAGS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cBi8fjv90E4&t=518s))

Then I started to research a better solution... What I've found.

We will need three plugins from Ionic

1. [@capacitor/status-bar](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/status-bar)
2. [@cordova/navigation-bar](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/navigation-bar)

Before jump to the implementation install the Capacitor and Cordova plugins correctly:

```
npm install rxjs
npm install @ionic-native/core
npm install @capacitor/status-bar
npm install cordova-plugin-navigationbar
npm install @ionic-native/navigation-bar

npx capacitor sync
```

[[1. HIDE NAVIGATION AND STATUS BAR]](http://#section-1)

So if we've installed the required plugins we can write a simple few lines of code.

```
/*This will be triggered when the component renders*/
import {StatusBar} from "@capacitor/status-bar";
import {NavigationBar} from '@ionic-native/navigation-bar';

export default class YOUR CLASS extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
        StatusBar.hide().then(r => ANY_CALLBACK);
        NavigationBar.hideNavigationBar().then(r => ANY_CALLBACK);
        }
}
```

As you wish you can do it in your App.tsx

```
import {StatusBar} from "@capacitor/status-bar";
import {NavigationBar} from '@ionic-native/navigation-bar';

//Simple function that has been called when the app load
function HideThings(){
        StatusBar.hide().then(r => ANY_CALLBACK);
        NavigationBar.hideNavigationBar().then(r => ANY_CALLBACK);
}

const App: React.FC = () => (
    <IonApp onLoad={HideThings}>
        <IonReactRouter>
...
```

Results:

[image: On pixel 4 emulator with capacitor/status-bar + cordova/navigation-bar]
[image: User pulled from top or bottom - show transparent status and nav bar]

**If you want to display on an edge-to-edge display like Samsung Galaxy A51 or any newer phone** you should have to set up your app as shown in [1. HIDE NAVIGATION AND STATUS BAR]

Then you should go to the

```
android/app/src/main/values
```

from here you need to copy the styles.xml
create a folder called `values-v28`

```
android/app/src/main/values-v28
```

Paste the styles.xml to the `values-v28`
then inside to the `<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">`
add a new item as shown below

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowLayoutInDisplayCutoutMode">shortEdges</item>
    </style>
```

After this, you are all set, and your application will render under the status bar.

> Cordova/Capacitor plugins work only with react and angular (Vue is not supported by the Cordova plugins)

> Edge-to-edge display should work fine in other android applications you just need to put it in the correct place [READ MORE](https://betterprogramming.pub/making-notch-friendly-apps-for-android-75776272be5c)